# How do you undelete files from within multiple levels of deleted folder on EXT4 and keep the original file tree structure?

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, testdisk

I was making some room n my file server by moving the data to the desktop.  The desktop had a catastrophic failure and now i'm trying to recover the files from the fileserver.
Trying to undelete close to 4tb of data from ext4 partition.

Here's the setup... 5 disk raid 6 (17TB used out of 22 TB total).  This mounts a LUKS partition, with an underlying EXT4 partition.

The EXT4 partition is perfectly readable, and I've set it to readonly.  Between the time of deletion and setting it to readonly, nothing has been written or moved around on the file server.  it has been rebooted once, and that was to reboot with the ext4 as readonly.

Can't image the disk because its 22TB.  The desktop is back up and running and has 8TB free space, so I have mounted part of the file system inside the file-server's file system to have a place to write the large amount of data i need to recover.

I found **testdisk** and it looks perfect for my use case.  I can see the deleted folders, but they all appear empty.

How can I get my deleted files back? and preferably the underlying folder structure they live in?

Please help.

I tried, [undelete files on ext4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217606/undelete-files-on-ext4) , but haven't been able to un-delete folders with all original files that were in it.  I suspect the mentioned post did not delete the actual /tmp folder.

Also read: [Testdisk brings back empty folders that take up space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705244/testdisk-brings-back-empty-folders-that-take-up-space) and [data recovery with testdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403883/data-recovery-with-testdisk?rq=1) , but I suspect these have to do with a windows-fs and not linux/ext4-fs.

Comment: Yes, I came across that post. Its what led me to testdisk.  The OP of that post however I suspect never deleted the TMP folder, and all the deleted files were inside it ready to be un-deleted.  However, all my files were inside various folders, which was deleted along with the files.  And when I look in those deleted folders to un-delete them using testdisk, they all appear empty with nothing inside to recover.  I un-deleted one such folder to test, but it did not recover any files.  I'm trying to un-delete complete directory sub-trees.